# If else statements using dict to select the right value

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm working on a Teamspeak 3 bot.

First I just want to say i'm very new to Python so there might be a simple solution to this, I dont know but I can not figure out how to do this.

What I have done is created a script that runs every 20 seconds. It will create a loop using all online connected clients and add 20 seconds to their total time online table in the database if they are not in the AFK channel and not a staff member. This I have created so far and it works.

The plan with this bot is to assign a new servergroup to the teamspeak client if it has been online for the required time to achieve the servergroup.

I have created three examples here:

```
serverGroups = {
    "Rookie": ("9", "3600"),
    "Member": ("10", "43200"),
    "Veteran": ("11", "172800")
}
```

In the Rookie group the name is ofcourse Rookie, the servergroup ID is 9 and the total time in seconds you need to achieve it is 3600.

I have the variables for all the needed information such as users current servergroup id and the total time online.

So basically what I can't figure out how to do is to write the code that checks if the user has reached the needed time for a new servergroup and if the user should be assigned to a new server group.

Do note that i can not change the servergroup everytime this runs as the user will hear it on his client so I can only assign the new group if the time has been reached and the user is not the usergroup he has reached. And later i will add more groups to the dict i used, that's the reason i'm asking here because i have been trying and trying to do this in a simple way where i do not have to go into the code and add alot of lines everytime I add a new servergroup.

What i'm trying to return from this is if servergroup should be changed and to which servergroup.

If I explained this poorly please tell me and I will try to rephrase it in a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: That's nice 'n all, but did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your planning/to-do lists.

Comment: I did ask a question, i need help with creating a way of doing this.

I said: What i'm trying to return from this is if servergroup should be changed and to which servergroup. Sorry if i explained it poorly.

Comment: why are you storing numbers as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to give a good example without details on the details of how the player information is stored, but something like this may be what you're looking for

```
def upgradeUserRank(playerScore):
    # :param playerscore: whatever variable
    # which contains the players newest time
    # after adding the 20 seconds
    #
    # returns the new player rank if they should
    # be upgraded, else None
    serverGroups = {
        "Rookie": ("9", "3600"),
        "Member": ("10", "43200"),
        "Veteran": ("11", "172800")
    }

    # invert the dictionary because we want to reference by times
    # scoreDict = {serverGroups[i][1]:i for i in serverGroups.keys()}
    scoreDict = {j[1]:i for i, j in serverGroups.items()}

    # iterate through the required times from greatest to least
    # so you don't return the lower ranks
    for i in sorted(scoreDict, key=lambda x:int(x), reverse=True):
        # Check if they've entered the new rank in the last 20 seconds
        # Otherwise, you'd suggest they should be updated
        # every 20s interval you check after the pass the
        # threshold
        if 0<=playerScore-int(i)<20:
            return scoreDict[i]
```

Comment: delete `.keys()`, its unnecessary. use `.items()` in `scoreDict`. `sorted` knows the `reverse=True`-argument.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed. Did some modifications to the if statement but other than that this was perfect!